# mongodb Grouping fields into a list

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have:

```
{
"name": "A Name"
"ph": {"phone": "1111"}
"alt_ph": {"phone": "2222"}
}
```

I would like to query mongo in a way the result is like the below:

```
"A Name": ["1111", "2222"]
```

and if possible the list to be unique.
Not sure how to go about it

Comment: Please share collection at jsoneditor online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) to make sure that your result contains unique values along with [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) combined with [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to get your key evaluated dynamically based on other field's value:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $arrayToObject: [[ { k: "$name", v: { $setUnion: [ ["$ph.phone"], ["$alt_ph.phone"] ] } } ]]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UbCi-1sD5RJ)

Comment: How can I remove the null or empty values too?

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/exbIU671yFj)

`
[
  {
    "A Name": [
      "1111",
      "2222"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Noel": [
      "",
      "1111"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Joey": [
      null,
      "1111"
    ]
  }
]
`

Comment: for removing `null` and `empty value` you can use `$cond` operator to check value of field and do steps according to if - else.

Comment: where exactly will you use the $cond? I tried it and it does not work. I put it in front of every field {$cond: } if front of [$ph.phone]

Comment: @sgp you can add `$filter` like https://mongoplayground.net/p/HT9ot3eFPSc

Comment: @mickl perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: 1 more step: I tried to add a filter to k,v if v is []. eg: https://mongoplayground.net/p/5sNqCrC6bwT
That did not work. Where should I be adding that filter? Or would it be something else like $pull or something?

Comment: Try to put $match before you run $replaceRoot: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gkzzs5n1mVA

Comment: @mickl - Thank you so much. I had been trying the $match at different place, but did not think of putting it before replaceRoot. I thank you so much for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I tried this & it's working, but not sure how to make it unique:

```
"$project": {
"_id": 0, "name": 1,
"phones": ["$ph", "$alt_ph"]
}
```

Gives me desired, but:
I will get null, if field is empty or field does not exist and i can get duplicates as well.